# SQL Server : auto-increment column in function of two columns values

Tags: sql-server

I want to produce a similar table that this table below.

In the first time, this table is create by another program but I must insert a new rows when an images is added.

For this, I have try this request but the select is done upstream of the insert and the Max function is useless.

`@idart` contains a table with multiple `CODE` and `ID_IMG` but without ORDER number.

```
INSERT INTO [NOMENC_ARTICLES_IMAGES]
    SELECT 
        I.CODE, I.ID As ID_IMG, 
        CASE 
           WHEN (SELECT MAX(AI.ORDRE) FROM [NOMENC_ARTICLES_IMAGES] AS AI  
                 WHERE AI.CODE = A.CODE) IS NULL 
              THEN 0 
              ELSE (SELECT MAX(AI.ORDRE) FROM [NOMENC_ARTICLES_IMAGES] AS AI  
                    WHERE AI.CODE = A.CODE) + 1 
        END AS ORDER
    FROM 
        @idart AS I 
    LEFT JOIN
        [NOMENC_ARTICLES_IMAGES] AS A ON A.CODE = I.CODE
```

[image]

Could you help me to increment the ORDER column in terms of `CODE` and `ID_IMG`?

EDIT :

In [NOMENC_ARTICLES_IMAGES] I have :

[image]

And I want to add 1, 2, x value contains in @idart.

**For exemple :**

@idart :

[image]

The expected result after insert :

[image]

I hope that with this example, you will better understand my need

Comment: This is not a great question - its not clear what you are trying to achieve here - you say you want to inrement order in terms of code and ID_IMG but in code 110026 the order is desc and in code 148000 its ASC ..

I would propose you look at using something like ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY ID_IMG DESC)

Comment: I'm sorry, it was not easy to put on paper.

The increment must be done according to the order of the insert.
There is no need for desc or asc.
I just have to increment the order value so that it is always only taking into consideration the existing order.

Using ROW_NUMBER will give me the same result, I think, since the insert will only be done afterwards.

Comment: cant you just add a timestamp of when you inserted the record and if you want to get an int off this use the  analytic features discussed on this ticket

Answer (score 0):

Use an [analytical function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) like this:

```
INSERT INTO [NOMENC_ARTICLES_IMAGES]
select I.CODE, I.ID As ID_IMG,
       row_number() over (partition by I.CODE order by I.ID) 
       + (select isnull(max(order), 0) from [NOMENC_ARTICLES_IMAGES] AS A ON A.CODE = I.CODE)
       As ORDER
FROM 
        @idart AS I
```

But pay attention, that you're always getting the highest order for the highest `I.ID` per `I.CODE`. In some cases that works, in others `I.ID` would not have to be strictly growing. Meaning the newest images wouldn't get the biggest `ORDER`'s

Comment: The logic is good but it doesn't take into account the highest indicator in the order column of [NOMENC_ARTICLES_IMAGES].
Suddenly, I find myself with several times with the same index.

Comment: Ok I adapted it, check if it fits your need.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've find the solution based on the answer of casenonsensitive :

```
INSERT INTO [NOMENC_ARTICLES_IMAGES]
SELECT I.CODE, I.ID As ID_IMG, 
   row_number() over (partition by I.CODE order by I.ID) + 
    CASE WHEN A.ORDER IS NULL THEN -1 ELSE A.ORDER END As ORDER
FROM 
    @idart AS I 
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT AI.CODE, MAX(AI.ORDER) As ORDER FROM [NOMENC_ARTICLES_IMAGES] As AI GROUP BY AI.CODE) AS A ON A.CODE = I.CODE
```

Thanks for all !